# M365 Group: update value of CreationOption

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-teams

### Inquiry/Questions

This is related to updating an M365 Group attribute `CreationOption` with a specific value of `"ExchangeProvisioningFlags:3552"` rather than an incorrect `null` per Microsoft basic support.

- <s>Can the `CreationOption` be updated with Global Admin access?</s>
- What proven methods have successfully facilitated this update?
- Are there specific pointers or command logic examples to efficiently update this attribute?
- Any nuance or pitfall insights from others overcoming similar attribute updates?

**Related Resources**

- [Resource behavior options not being properly set by aad o365group add](https://github.com/pnp/cli-microsoft365/issues/5408)

  > *milanholemans commented on Aug 27, 2023*
  >
  > All right found the culprit for this issue. Will provide a PR with the
  > fix. Thank you for bringing this to the surface @alpozz!
  >
  > > This change probably occurred sometime around May-June 2023. Groups I've created in May and early June were configured correctly, but groups created in early August appear not.
  >
  > In that case, probably something changed on the API we use because I can't see any significant changes since this option was introduced.
- [Provision resources for a group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/group-set-options#provision-resources-for-a-group)

  > `resourceProvisioningOptions` is a string collection that specifies group resources to be provisioned as part of the Microsoft 365 group. These resources can be specified during group creation ***or update***.
  >
  > **Supported values for resource** : `team`
  >
  > **Description** :  Provision a team for this group in Microsoft
  > Teams. Additionally, this value can also be added on [group update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-update)
  > through a `PATCH` operation, in order to provision a team from an
  > existing Microsoft 365 group. If not set, the Microsoft 365 group
  > isn't associated with a team.

#### Self-Efforts

- Installed latest versions of Cloud Sync and Entra Connect; verified absence of on-prem to Azure AD sync errors.
- Conducted backend comparisons with functioning groups; inconsistency not identified.
- Added and removed members to other Teams existing before Exchange decommissioning; no issues.
- Newly created M365 Team-enabled groups function correctly upon access grant.
- Users granted access to problematic Team encounter issues; access seems limited to those with prior access only.
- Opened Microsoft support service tickets for further investigation.

Furthermore, I'll start digging into the Microsoft documents regarding `group update` and `patch` operations. To streamline my research and testing, I'm seeking more precise starting points or guidance from others knowledgeable in this area.

**PowerShell Attempt & Detail**

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'Group.ReadWrite.All'
$group = Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Broken Team'"
$creationOptions = @{
    ExchangeProvisioningFlags = 3552
}

$updateObject = @{
    creationOptions = $creationOptions
    resourceBehaviorOptions = @("HideGroupInOutlook", "WelcomeEmailDisabled", "SubscribeMembersToCalendarEventsDisabled")
    resourceProvisioningOptions = @("Team")
    serviceProvisioningErrors = @()
}
$json = $updateObject | ConvertTo-Json
Update-MgGroup -GroupId $group.Id -BodyParameter $json
```

**Error Output**

```
Update-MgGroup : An unexpected 'StartObject' node was found for property named 'creationOptions' when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartArray' node was expected.
At line:21 char:1
+ Update-MgGroup -GroupId $group.Id -BodyParameter $jsonPayload
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ GroupId = 5df...oftGraphGroup }:<>f__AnonymousType0`2) [Update-MgGroup_Update1], RestException`1
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Request_BadRequest,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.UpdateMgGroup_Update1
```

**Broken Team Get**

```
(Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Broken Team'").AdditionalProperties
```

**Output**

```
Key                         Value 
---                         ----- 
creationOptions             {}    
resourceBehaviorOptions     {}    
resourceProvisioningOptions {Team}
serviceProvisioningErrors   {}
```

```
(Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Broken Team'").AdditionalProperties | Select-Object Keys, Values | Format-List
```

**Output**

```
Keys   : {creationOptions, resourceBehaviorOptions, resourceProvisioningOptions, serviceProvisioningErrors}
Values : {System.Object[], System.Object[], Team, System.Object[]}
```

**Working Team Get**

```
(Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Working Team'").AdditionalProperties
```

**Output**

```
Key                         Value                                                                               
---                         -----                                                                               
creationOptions             {ExchangeProvisioningFlags:3552}                                                    
resourceBehaviorOptions     {HideGroupInOutlook, WelcomeEmailDisabled, SubscribeMembersToCalendarEventsDisabled}
resourceProvisioningOptions {Team}                                                                              
serviceProvisioningErrors   {}
```

```
(Get-MgGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Working Team'").AdditionalProperties | Select-Object Keys, Values | Format-List
```

**Output**

```
Keys   : {creationOptions, resourceBehaviorOptions, resourceProvisioningOptions, serviceProvisioningErrors}
Values : {ExchangeProvisioningFlags:3552, HideGroupInOutlook WelcomeEmailDisabled SubscribeMembersToCalendarEventsDisabled, Team, System.Object[]}
```

---

### The Story/Issue

In an M365 tenant, most Team-enabled M365 groups function similarly and were created using identical PowerShell commands. However, **one Team group does NOT appear** in either version of the Teams desktop app or teams.microsoft.com for newly granted members or owners.

Although other features such as SharePoint and Azure settings function properly, the Team and chat functions are inaccessible for newly granted member or owner access, despite being correctly listed as such in all M365 portals where checked.

#### Microsoft Service Tickets

I raised a Teams service ticket with Microsoft for resolution/troubleshooting assistance. Despite a week-long diagnostic, they advised contacting the Azure team since they found no issues.

The Azure team then discovered that the `CreationOption` for this group is `null`, unlike the expected value of `"ExchangeProvisioningFlags:3552"`, which is set for properly functioning Team groups.

- **Note:** All other Microsoft 365 Teams-enabled groups, which were created using the same PowerShell commands during the presence of Exchange 2010 in the on-premise environment with null values, appear to function correctly.

  > **Works correct many other M365 Groups**
  >
  > ```
  > Key                         Value 
  > ---                         ----- 
  > creationOptions             {}    
  > resourceBehaviorOptions     {}    
  > resourceProvisioningOptions {Team}
  > serviceProvisioningErrors   {}
  > ```

I'll suggest this go to the SharePoint Microsoft 365 Team next. The Azure Team has mainly compared the two new groups created post-Exchange 2010 decommissioning and post-Exchange 2016. However, all other groups created pre-Exchange 2016 with null values continue to grant access correctly to Teams app, chat, etc. If I figure out a way to get the attributes updated, I will still try that regardless.

#### Recent Changes

If this is even applicable, perhaps an Exchange 2010 hybrid separation, or transitioning to Exchange 2016 contributed to nullifying a certain attribute of the M365 group, causing the Team to not display for **new members and owners on both the app and Teams.Microsoft.com (V1 and V2)**.

#### Hybrid Environment

We're currently managing AD account Exchange attributes with a single Exchange 2016 server and plan to transition to Exchange 2019 and eventually Exchange Online, all managed solely through PowerShell.

We have an Entra Connect server using both Cloud Sync (filtered OUs) and Entra Connect which also assists with the M365 cloud created groups being populated back in the specific OU in on-premise AD via Group writeback.

Comment: Here's a github where I believe this affects the issues in this case too in case it helps anyone with knowledge tell me what further to try. I will next week setting only one value at a time with the logic in the question in case you can only update one value at a time e.g. `creationOption` and then `resourceBehaviorOptions` subsequent separate command. Sounds like the `creationOption` is what MS says to update only to fix the problem. Otherwise, I'll test the same with a comand  similar to `New-PnPMicrosoft365Group` but for updating if applicable.

Comment: GitHub bug finding post also talking about code versions, etc. it was introduce into the MS Graph API, will dig more next week though: https://github.com/pnp/cli-microsoft365/issues/5408. Coffee and googling on the weekend before non-work fun begins.