# Error Cloning Microsoft Teams Group with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm currently working with Microsoft support on a ticket related to updating the value of `CreationOption` for an M365 Group, as discussed in this post: [M365 Group: update value of CreationOption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036590/m365-group-update-value-of-creationoption). While awaiting a resolution, I attempted to clone the problematic Team group to a new Team-enabled M365 group.

However, I've encountered errors during the cloning process and am seeking insights or suggestions from the community. Specifically, I'm wondering if there are adjustments I can make to the scope permissions or other settings to troubleshoot the issue.

Below is the PowerShell script I've used for the cloning attempt, along with the error message received:

### PowerShell

```
Install-Module Microsoft.Graph.Teams -Force
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Teams -MinimumVersion 2.15.0
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Group.Read.All, Team.ReadBasic.All, TeamSettings.Read.All, TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All

# Get the Teams you have access to
##$teams = Get-MgTeam

# List all teams with their IDs
##$teams | Select-Object DisplayName, Id | Sort DisplayName

# Define parameters for the new team
$params = @{
    displayName = "Problem Team Copy"
    description = "Testing copy of Problem Team"
    mailNickname = "problemcopytest"
    partsToClone = "apps,tabs,settings,channels"
    visibility = "private"
}

$teamId = "8xxxxx88-xx8x-8xx8-8888-896x7x019xx4"

Copy-MgTeam -TeamId $teamId -BodyParameter $params
```

#### Error

```
Copy-MgTeam : Unable to fetch team thread: Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadRequest.
Status: 403 (Forbidden)
ErrorCode: Forbidden
Date: 2024-03-06T13:28:33
Headers:
Transfer-Encoding             : chunked
Vary                          : Accept-Encoding
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000
request-id                    : 8xx8xx8x-88xx-88x8-8x8x-514xx5x4x4x1
client-request-id             : 8x88xx88-88x8-88xx-8xxx-822x560x93x2
x-ms-ags-diagnostic           : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Central US","Slice":"E","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"003","RoleInstance":"CH01EPF0002DB18"}}
Date                          : Wed, 06 Mar 2024 13:28:32 GMT
At line:15 char:1
+ Copy-MgTeam -TeamId $teamId -BodyParameter $params
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ TeamId = 8xxx...ionJsonSchema }:<>f__AnonymousType3`3) [Copy-MgTeam_Clone], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Forbidden,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.CopyMgTeam_Clone
```

Any advice or guidance on resolving this error and successfully cloning the Microsoft Teams group would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not knowing 100% for certain what IDs are sensitive or not, I have masked out the `$teamId`, `request-id`, and `client-request-id ` characters out with mostly "`x`" and "`8`" characters from a privacy perspective if that's even applicable.

Comment: To resolve the error do `Connect-MgGraph -scopes Team.Create`

Comment: @Rukmini Unfortunately, I get the same error and I tried after disconnecting and reconnecting twice with both `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Team.Create` and then `Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Group.Read.All, Team.ReadBasic.All, TeamSettings.Read.All, TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All,Team.Create` and both give the same error result. Please let me know if you have any other ideas and thank you!

Comment: Try with Directory.ReadWrite.All too

Comment: I tried in my environment and was able to successfully clone team. Which account are you using to connect to MgGraph?/

Comment: @Rukmini I tried again and get the same exact error result adding in the new `Directory.ReadWrite.All` permissions disconnecting and reconnecting trying twice. I am using my personal Global Administrator account to do this. I wonder if it's corrupt and will just not work for cloning too with the other post that I'm waiting on MS support to give advice or guidance.

Comment: Note that you cloning team doesnt support for Personal Microsoft account you need to login with work or school account

Comment: Check [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/W4Q5DFJ.png) and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-clone?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#permissions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257090/discussion-between-rukmini-and-bitcoin-murderous-maniac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***When I executed the same script in my environment it worked successfully:***

```bash
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Group.Read.All, Team.ReadBasic.All, TeamSettings.Read.All, TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All

$params = @{
    displayName = "Problem Team Copy"
    description = "Testing copy of Problem Team"
    mailNickname = "problemcopytest"
    partsToClone = "apps,tabs,settings,channels"
    visibility = "public"
}

$teamId = "TeamID"

Copy-MgTeam -TeamId $teamId -BodyParameter $params
```

The team got cloned successfully like below:

[image]

*With the same permissions as you, I am able to clone the team.*

***If still the issue persists, check the below:***

- According to this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-clone?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell#permissions), **`Team.Create`** permission is required to clone the team. If still the error occurs then pass scope as **`Team.Create`** .
- As mentioned by you, the team you are trying to clone is corrupted, try to fix the corrupted team and then you will be able to clone it.
- As it is working for the other team the issue is due to the corrupted team. Once the issue fixes rerun the script and the team will be cloned.

Comment: Thank you, I will be back to accept this answer later when I get the corruption fixed!! I appreciate your time, effort, and feedback. +1

Comment: @BitcoinMurderousManiac did you resolve your issue

Comment: Accepted as promised, solution has stuck since Monday so seems to be what it was. See self-answer added for more specifics of what resolved in my case. The M365 Support Team told me the Azure Support Team should have found this when the ticket was passed to them. In any case, I shared the solution with them, and the ticket was closed yesterday. I was told it'd be documented on their side as well to help other customers more quickly potentially that run into this issue.

Comment: Great to hear that the issue is resolved

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering issues with Team-enabled Microsoft 365 Groups sourced from the cloud, configured for [Dynamic Group Membership](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/users/groups-dynamic-membership) via rules, and experiencing [sporadic failures in honoring these rules for member (and/or owner) access to Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78036590/m365-group-update-value-of-creationoption), this **solution** might be applicable to your situation.

[image]

Despite being an owner of a Group for several weeks, it appeared that the error encountered while running the `Copy-MgTeam` command stemmed from access issues with backend systems.

Granting new owner access seemed to be impacted by the issue most of the time. Once the solution was effective, owner permissions worked as expected, and the `Copy-MgTeam` command worked properly too without error.

## Self-Solution

**Important:** Backup the **Dynamic membership rules** if necessary before following these steps.

1. Within **Microsoft Entra admin center**, go to the **Group**.
2. Click **Properties**, change **Membership type** to "**Assigned**", and press **Save**.
3. Go to **Manage** | **Members**, and **explicitly remove members from the group** within Entra while leaving owners as-is.
4. Now is **the important part of waiting for all environmental and system replication to occur** within your environment, step away for an hour or longer if possible (e.g. after close of business).
5. Confirm with Entra Admin, Teams Admin, and M365 Admin Centers that the members are all removed as per **#3** from the Group.
6. As per **#2**, now toggle **Membership type** to "**Dynamic**", and press **Save**.
7. Go to **Dynamic membership rules**, and add/edit back in the necessary membership rules, and press **Save**.
8. Once again, **wait for all environmental and system replication to occur** within your environment, step away for a while, etc.
9. Confirm in all the M365 admin portals again **#5**, that now all members are listed correctly.

   - Confirm any newly grant Team "Owners" and "Members" access is back working.
   - Confirm from **Teams desktop app as owner** from the **Manage Team** option, that all members are assigned per the dynamic membership rules as expected.

     [image]

#### Tip

Begin by confirming that an existing owner of the Team can access the '**Manage Team**' option in the Teams app. Compare the Teams app members with all the M365 admin portals against the group's membership.

If discrepancies are observed between the membership displayed in the Teams app and the expected membership shown in the M365 admin portals, switching the Group configuration to 'assigned,' removing all members explicitly, allowing sufficient time for replication, and then reverting the configuration back to 'Dynamic' may resolve.